# Ruby on Rails: weird missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to RoR, I typed in the shopping cart tutorial from richonrails, and got this error, however if i run the code from github, there is no issue.

The missing template seems to be looking for a create.html.erb, i created it and somehow the page is rendered, but the correct file to render is create.js.erb

I tried using respond_to change it to js, this, however does not exist in the original code from github.

my code is at https://github.com/poiuyo/shopcart
richonrails tutorial is at https://github.com/RichIsOnRails/ShoppingCartExampleApp

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

```
error on respond_to 
respond_to do |format|
if @order.save
      format.js 




order_items_controller.rb
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
   @order = current_order
   @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
   @order.save
   session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end
private
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id)
  end
end



create.js.erb
<% if @order.errors.any? || @order_item.errors.any? %>
alert("not valid.")
<% else %>
  $(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>")
<% end %>
```

Comment: on your github repository you have 2 system folders hierarchy 'app'  nested one inside other

Comment: Thanks fellons, there are other files which is repeating, I updated the github files and remove i hope all the same folders but the persists. It seems my ones have this Processing by OrderitemsController#create as HTML but the original one is as JS. How to switch it to JS?

Comment: link_to from which start action, must have :remote => true param

Comment: the remote: true exists in all the views, but it does not render. getting frustrated. but it still formats as html

Comment: try to add a <script type="text/javascript"> tag (with something inside ... alert or a some stupid function) at the end of the your root html file. Verify also your page source code, from browser, if href have data-remote="true"